# Can't subset columns past the end

Tags: r

We extracted a column from our dataframe(called "DT") that we had to test for reliability by using the Cronbach alpha.

The code we used to extract the data was:

`Mydata_age <- DT %>% select(as.numeric(as.character(DT$Q7...23)))`

We did this because at first "DT$Q7...23" did not give us a numeric value, even though it contained ages of participants in a survey we made and used to extract our data from.

However, when we ran the code it keeps saying

> Can't subset columns past the end
> There are only 24 columns

We expected Mydata_age to work and then to run `Alpha(Mydata_age)` to give us a value.

Comment: Do the transformation within `mutate/transmute`.  Also, to select columns if the name is nonstandard, use backquotes around it.  i.e. `DT %>% transmute(`Q7...23` = `as.numeric(as.character(`Q7...23`)))`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.